# How to theme mat-chip?

Tags: angular-material

How do I theme an unselected `<mat-chip>One fish</mat-chip>` to have a white background and a grey border?

Modifying the primary and secondary color palettes only affects the selected chips:

```
<mat-chip color="primary" selected>Primary fish</mat-chip>
<mat-chip color="accent" selected>Accent fish</mat-chip>
```

I have only been able to affect unselected mat-chips through CSS:

```
::ng-deep .mat-chip.mat-standard-chip {
  background: white;
  color: $charcoal;
  border: 1px solid #B7B8BB;
  border-radius: 16px;
  font-family: Roboto-Regular;
  margin-right: 8px;
  padding: 7px 16px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: lowercase;
  outline: none;
}
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

style your components in the root css "styles.css". Don't use *::ng-deep* because it´s deprecated!!!

Comment: Thx for the reply . Is there a way to apply a custom theme to the disabled chips? Or must I rely on CSS?

Comment: I would rely on CSS and use themes just for redesign for the whole page, e.g. dark theme

Answer (score 0):

You can build a theme with the use of `mat-light-theme` function from material/theming.
Then, you can do:

```
$bg: map-get($yourTheme, background);
```

You get a map in $bg.

And later, you need to **merge** your new style for unselected chips with this `$bg` map. You can do so with:

```
$yourNewColor: #fefefe; // or map-get($anotherMapWithColors, 600)
$bg: map-merge($bg, (unselected-chip: $yourNewColor));
$chip-theme: map-merge($yourTheme, (background: $bg));
```

Your theme map for the chips is ready. You can then create the theme for chips using:

```
// from styles.scss
@include theming.mat-chips-theme(light-theming.$wkc-chips-theme);
```